# is this the way of installing python libraries on mac?

Tags: python

i am an extreme noob in python programming and i decided to learn tkinter. But i can't install tkinter on may mac. I don't know what the problem is can someone help me please?

```
pip3 install tkinter
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tkinter (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tkinter
```

this is the end result what to do?
`

Comment: The way you're calling pip is correct, but you can't use pip to install tkinter. If you have python, it probably came with tkinter already installed.

Answer (score 0):

You should install Tkinter through the brew:

```
brew install tcl-tk
brew uninstall python3
brew install python3 --with-tcl-tk
```

Comment: when i run the command: 'brew install python3' its showing 'Error: No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/python' what to do?